# Norms are equivalent if one hand side of inequality holds

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $(X,\|.\|_1)$ and $(X,\|.\|_2)$ are Banach spaces and $\forall x \in X$. Show that if  $\|.\|_1 \le k \|.\|_2 $ for $\exists k \gt 0$ then $\|.\|_1$ and $ \|.\|_2 $ are equivalent.

I could think only belows

$(x_n)$ is an arbitrary Cauchy Sequence in $X$ and since it is Banach wrt $ \|.\|_2 $ thus $\exists x \in X$ such that

$\|x_n-x\|_2 \lt \varepsilon /k$

From inequeality we have

$\|x_n-x\|_1 \le k\|x_n-x\|_2 \lt \varepsilon$  hence $x_n \to x$ wrt $\|.\|_1$ norm.

I cannot continue and I think there are some mistakes and deficiencies my writtens above.

I will be apreciated for any help

---

I have used a version of Banach Isomorphism Theorem thanks to your comments :

Let $I:(X,\|.\|_2) \to (X,\|.\|_1)$ identity map. It is (1-1) and onto.

$\|I(x)\|_1 = \|x\|_1 \le k\|x\|_1 $ thus $I$ is bounded and equivalently continuous.

By Banach Isomorphism Theorem it is a homeomorphism hence $I^{-1}$ is continuous and equivalently bounded.

We can find $\exists c \gt 0$ such that

$\|I^{-1}(x)\|_2 = \|x\|_2 \le c\|x\|_1 $

Finally we get the norms are equivalent

Could you please check it?

Comment: Hint : Bounded inverse theorem, on the identity map between $X$ with each norm.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I am sorry I dont know that theorem

Comment: Do you know the open mapping theorem, then? Without this, you would be in trouble.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Yes I know it should I define a mapping? Could you please give an abstract proof?

Comment: The answer below mentions the identity map, which is continuous (one way) and surjective. Now you can conclude.

Comment: Maybe you prefer to use the closed graph theorem.  In any case, the completeness is important; this fails for normed spaces in general.

Comment: @GEdgar Is it possible to prove it with closed graph theorem but without tautological maps and isomorphisms?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I can use open mapping theorem with using identity map. Am I right?

Comment: I guess you could try to use the Baire category theorem directly.  The whole space is a countable union of closed balls in one norm, use your inequality with Baire category to show one of those balls has nonempty interior in the other norm.

Comment: @user519955 Yes, that is right.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I think I used the theorem you ve mentioned first. Could you please check? I’ve edited question. In addition very thanks for concerning

Comment: Yes, the proof is exactly what I would have done too, and is correct. +1.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Aww really thanks. Your comments have been very beneficial for me. Kind regards

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

You just need to prove that $id: (X,\lVert \bullet\rVert_2)\to (X,\lVert \bullet\rVert_1)$ is continuous. In other words, by the closed graph theorem, that the set $\Delta^2_1:=\{(x,x)\,:\, x\in X\}$ is a closed subset of the Banach space $(X\times X,\lVert \bullet\rVert_{1\otimes 2})$, where $\lVert (x_1,x_2)\rVert_{1\otimes 2}=\lVert x_1\rVert_1+\lVert x_2\rVert_2$. This is the case if and only if the normed space $(\Delta^2_1,\lVert \bullet\rVert_{1\otimes 2})$ is a Banach space.

The fact that $id': (X,\lVert \bullet\rVert_1)\to (X,\lVert \bullet\rVert_2)$ is continuous gives you that $(\Delta^1_2,\lVert \bullet\rVert_{2\otimes 1})$ is a Banach space. But the tautological map $\Delta^1_2\ni (x,x)\mapsto (x,x)\in\Delta^2_1$ is a bijective isometry. Thus, $\Delta_1^2$ is Banach as well.

Comment: Firstly thank you. I don’t know anything about tautological maps and isometries in functional analysis. I’m in an elementary grade in functional analysis. Is it possible to simplify that proof? Could you please simplify if it is possible?

Comment: @user519955 "Tautological map" is just a term that I use to indicate a map that sends each object to itself, but in an ambient space endowed with a different structure. Namely, at a closer inspection the sets $\Delta^1_2$ and $\Delta_1^2$ are *the same set*, and the two restrictions of the norms $\lVert \bullet\rVert_{1\otimes 2}$ and $\lVert \bullet\rVert_{2\otimes 1}$ to it are *exactly the same function*. However, at that point of the discussion I must still work as if $\Delta_1^2$ and $\Delta_2^1$ were endowed with two different norms (since the two norms are different on $X\times X$).

Comment: thanks a lot for concerning

Comment: Note that if $X$ is a topological space, then $\Delta = \{(x,x) : x \in X\}$ is a closed set in $X \times X$ if and only if $X$ is Hausdorff. I believe it has nothing to do with completeness of your normed space (other that you can't use the closed graph theorem otherwise).

Comment: @mechanodroid The fact is that I cannot assume in advance that those two $X$'s are the same topological space, because it is not given that the norms are equivalent. Namely, I have the topological spaces $(X,\tau_1)$, $(X,\tau_2)$, and $(X\times X,\tau_1\times\tau_2)$, while that lemma applies to $(X\times X,\tau_1\times \tau_1)$ or $(X\times X,\tau_2\times \tau_2)$.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path You are right, my mistake.